# Django doesn't show model in admin

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and I have simple model like this.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Todo(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    done = models.BooleanField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class News(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(max_length=400000)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=400000)
    created     = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    modified    = models.DateTimeField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' On save, update timestamps '''
        if not self.id:
            self.created = timezone.now()
        self.modified = timezone.now()
        return super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

In url,

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from todo import views
from rest_framework import viewsets, routers
from django.contrib import admin

router = routers.DefaultRouter()

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
 )
```

I check in stackoverflow and they say autodiscover should be removed. But if I remove, I see like this. How shall I do so that my model is shown in admin?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your admin.py file do this

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Todo, News

# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Todo)
admin.site.register(News)
```

Your app is probably not registered in `INSTALLED_APPS`, if it dosent' find your app it fails without giving an error

Answer (score 1):

You must register model in admin app

see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects